# Hive select a column based on a second column where the second column values are different

Tags: sql, select, group-by, hive, having-clause

Let's say we have a hive table with 4 different columns and I want to select from it for those values in the first column while make sure the values are different in the second column. Any help or guidance to how to do it?

```
  ---------------------
  | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
  ---------------------
  | a     1    g.   h |
  | a     1    f.   l |   
  | a     3    t.   p |  
  | b     1    r.   o |  
  | b     1    e.   q |
  | c     1    w.   w |
  | c     2    z.   p |
   -------------------
```

In the above example, I want to hive select return `a` and `c` because their values at C2 are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want `c1`s that have more than one distinct value in `c2`.

You can group by `c1`, and use a `having` clause with `count(distinct)` to implement the filtering:

```
select c1 
from mytable
group by c1
having count(distinct c2) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you, it will show C1 vales where there is only one match to the C1 + C2 combination

```
select distinct C1 from table
group by C1, C2
having count(*) = 1;
```

Very few lines so you should be able to figure out what it does.